# How to enable Alexa skill for beta testing on second Echo device

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit, beta-testing

I have created my first Alexa skill and all is going well in that:

- I have connected the skill to my own https service.
- I have added myself to the beta test program.
- I have got this all working perfectly using my Echo dot (about 2 years old).

In order to make testing easier I have purchased a new Echo device that can sit on my desk.  My problem is this new Echo will simply not work with my Alexa skill.  I have checked the language settings as others suggest, in fact, I've every single setting for my Echo and Echo Dot and they're **all exactly the same**.

I have tried removing myself from the beta testing and re-adding and I have tried de-registering each device but nothing helps.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks

Stu

Comment: You can add the email address for beta testing.
Navigate to your Skill Console > Distribution > Availability > "Beta Test'

Comment: Yes, I’ve done that in order to get my Echo Dot working. Are you saying I need a different email address & Amazon account per device?

Comment: The skill is whitelisted against email addresses and no restrictions to devices as such. You should be able to beta test your skill on the other device as long as the email address is the same.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  That's pretty much my point.  The two devices are setup with the same email address, same language, same everything but my new Echo just doesn't recognise the 'dev skill'.